# why my AuthGuard didn't works, BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript

Help pls, to make it work. isLoggedIn$ = this._isLoggedIn$.asObservable() always false, but when i make login _isLoggedIn$ true

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  private _isLoggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  public isLoggedIn$ = this._isLoggedIn$.asObservable();
  role: String | null;


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  login(form: FormGroup) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/api/login`, form.getRawValue(), {headers: headers, withCredentials: true}).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        this._isLoggedIn$.next(true);
        this.role = response.role;
      })
    );
  }
}





@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class IsAuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | Observable<boolean | UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
    | boolean
    | UrlTree {
    console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn$)
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn$;
  }
}
```

i tried through this.authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(tap(  but nothing, what i do wrong?

Comment: Have you added it to the routes?

Comment: ofc, the problem is that the value of true is not set

Comment: To clarify, this `console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn$)` shows anything?

Comment: yes, it shows false

Comment: after calling login the value should change to true.
Do you provide anywhere the  AuthService  service? If you do, you shouldn't because it will create another instance.

Comment: no, i use authService in login.component -->
    this.authService.login(this.form)
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(["/start"])
      },
      error => {
      this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
      });
  }

Comment: @alin0509 now I have changed this.router.navigate(["/start"]) to authenticated url and he switched to it with the value true, but I need it so that after logging in it does not immediately go to a secure page, but by clicking

Comment: @alin0509 
Now I read that the BehaviorSubject resets the value when the page is updated, some use localStorage, but the values it can be changed through the Browser DevTool, what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

When you use Observables as a return value of Guards, those Observables should complete. This is not the case in your example, since your using a Subject as a source.

To solve it you could use either `first()` operator

```
return this.authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(first());
```

Or `take(1)`

```
return this.authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(take(1));
```

You can read more about it in the docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-5-route-guards)

cheers